# status of records

Tags: java, jdbc, plsql

I have a requirement to generate large number of random data(Around 1 to 10 lakhs). Right the implementation is as follows. Calling a pl-sql procedure to generate the random data and storing it in a temporary table. Front end retrieves data in batches as required and displays to the user.
The new requirement requires us to display the % of records generated when the process is going on.
Is there any way of EFFICIENTLY generating this large in java itself( To know the generation status) and then store it into a table.

Comment: You don't necessarily need to move the generation code to Java - you can just call PL/SQL from java and update status accordingly. If you just called a pl/sql which generated 10% of the data, report 10% back to the user. Unless reported % has to be fine-grained below what pl/sql batch can generate as a minimum?

Comment: I would think Java could do this more efficiently than Oracle - generate the data in a file, give progress and then set the file as an external table in Oracle.

Comment: That's provided you have shell access to the oracle box, which we don't know if is possible. (This will take a lot of heap space, too)
My solution is the best for the lot of unknowns in this problem :) (what is efficiency, fast calling random() method? fast passing large chunks to db?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just fake it?  Calculate the average time it takes to generate 100,000 records and then advance a thermometer in 100ths of that time.  You will need to include a hang at 99% if the process takes longer than average, and a speedy finish if it compl